# How to enable a button just the moment when all the fields are filled up?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller where I have two textfields and a button. In viewDidLoad I have set the button disabled. Now I want to enable the button just the moment when I fill up both the fields. Please help me how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is not to disable a button rather check on button click if both the textfields are filled in.

Comment: I am a new joinee to a company and I have given this task but I am not able to do this. So I wanted a little help. Thats all.

Comment: dude, being a new person at a company has nothing to do with being a developer.

Comment: dude, I have joined an IT company as an ios app developer.

Comment: @Tirthendu : check my answer.. it will do what you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html). Let your viewController to implement the delegate method. The one most important is [- textFieldShouldReturn:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:) method. It's called when the return button of the keyboard is pressed. You can resignFirstResponder of the TextField & then check each TextField for the validity text. When all the textFields are containing some value, you may proceed to enable the set of buttons. This Will make your button appear when you edit the last text field & press the return button of the keyboard.

If you wanna enable the button whenever the textFields are filled up with the text, then implementation of the [- textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing:). This will fired up each time you change the text inside the UITextField. So inside this method checking all your textField is a good oppurtunity.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    textField1.delegate = self;
    textField2.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField1.text.length>=1 && textField2.text.length>=1) {
        yourButton.enable = YES;
    } else {
        yourButton.enable = NO;
    }
}
```

I believe you are done.

### Note :

As this was sample code I didn't consider trim.

You will need to trim the textfield text and compare the size and then use above code.

Comment: Dude, the button gets enabled just the moment I am clicking on any of the textfields. But I want the the button to be enabled only when one letter or number or anything is entered in both of the textfields.

Comment: @Tirthendu : that means if you have data in username & password then enable Login button... else disable... right?

Comment: I am learning and building the basic projects at the same time.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: One error is coming, "Control reaches end of non-void function".

Answer (score -1):

@**Tirthendu**

U can try below Code,I have Tested Below METHOD , MAY BE USEFUL TO YOU.

```
- (IBAction)btnProceedClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSString *aStrMSG; //Here tfFullname & tfEmailAddress is UITextField

    if([tfFullName.text length] == 0)
    {
        aStrMSG = @"Please insert FullName";
    }
    else if([tfEmailAddress.text length] == 0)
    {
        aStrMSG = @"Please insert Email Address";
    }



    if([aStrMSG length] > 0)
    {
        showAlertView(aStrMSG);
//SET ALERT that Enter Value in UiTextField
    }
    else
    {
        //Set your Button Enable Here.. & Process Method
    }
}
```